# How to create postman multipart/form-data request with an embedded file?

Tags: postman, multipartform-data

I'm creating a set of postman requests, in a collection, so that I can test an endpoint which accepts file uploads. I need to embed files in the request because otherwise the test collection isn't self contained and can't be used in the postman runner directly.

I can "embed" text files without line breaks (CRLF) but I can't embed binary files since they contain CRLFs.

Ways to embed single line text files

- Embed single line text files

  - This can be achieved by setting a custom header and body

Header

```
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------separator
```

Body (raw type)

```
----------------------------separator
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="file.json"
Content-Type: application/json

{ "id": "ecee0102-51c9-4a86-b5e7-0378f117f991" }
----------------------------separator--
```

- "Embed" big single-line files using a pre-request script

Header

```
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------separator
```

Body (raw type)

```
----------------------------separator
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="file.json"
Content-Type: application/json

{{tooBigFileContent}}
----------------------------separator--
```

Pre-request script

```
pm.globals.set("tooBigFileContent", "9".repeat((10*1024*1024)+1));
```

Things I have tried but didn't work

- Try to inject file contents into the body, decoding base64 to "binary", using pre-request script
- Try to use Content-Transfer-Encoding with base64 (the endpoint doesn't support the encoding

Ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: I am not sure if there are other ways, but when I had a similar requirement, I ended up using Newman to embed the files.

Comment: I have seen that tip of Newman but I really want make it easier to use for other and that's probably Postman.